# Dynamically change the where clause in the SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I building Angular application where I need to call the .net core API and return result. There are two fields in the angular application like below

[image]

Both the fields can be selected , may be just one field will be selected and result needs to be fetched from the API depending on the selection

My Query like below if both the fields are selected

```
  Select prj_number,location from sTable where r_proj = '000634' AND sdate = '2019-07-01' group by prj_number,location
```

And if just reporting project is just selected then

```
 Select prj_number,location from sTable where r_proj = '000634'  group by prj_number,location
```

Likewise for duration, Dynamically Change the where clause depending on the selection made from Angular.

I thought of building a string expression in Angular depending on the selection like

```
     string para = r_proj = '000634' AND sdate = '2019-07-01'
```

and pass into the Query like

```
  Select prj_number,location from sTable where @para  group by prj_number,location
```

But this didnt work, I get error like `'An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'group'.'`and looks like I cant pass expression as a parameter. How can I approach this scenario

Comment: To my understanding, your sdate has to be range of date like sdate>'2018-01-01' and sdate<'2018-12-31' when you select 'Last Year' as Duration. Is not it?

Comment: @SelimMahmud It is just an example but it will be the date '2019-07-01'

Comment: I would say angular should send an object like {reportingProject: '000634', duration: 'LastYear'|null}. And the back end .net api will produce the SQL.

Comment: "Didn't work" is not a description of an issue. Please post the code you used and the error / behaviour you got.

Comment: Generally speaking, you cannot parameterize sections of a query or identifiers (table name, column name) in a sql statement. You will need to build your sql statement based on the selected options and add any parameters to it as needed. What you don't want to do is use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I added the error message I got.

Comment: You build an entire literal string with the query in it inside ANgular and submit that string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make each parameter "optional" as follows:

```
DECLARE @projIdFilter varchar(10) = null
DECLARE @sdateFilter datetime = null

SELECT prj_number,location 
FROM sTable 
WHERE (@projIdFilter is null or r_proj = @projIdFilter) -- parenthesis are important
  AND (@sdateFilter is null or sdate = @sdateFilter)
GROUP BY prj_number,location
```